# Make Papertrail active only for certain methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, paper-trail-gem

As part of a performance update, I noticed some gems like Papertrail retrieve `current_user` using before_filter, so it happens for every request, which seems excessive as we only need it if the user is creating/updating/deleting.

I know I can limit papertrail by controller by overriding `paper_trail_enabled_for_controller`, but is there a way to make it active only for e.g. create/update/destroy methods?

Comment: [As of 5.0.0](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-5), PT no longer adds the `set_paper_trail_whodunnit` callback for you. That might be what's causing the `current_user` query. What version of PT are you using?